# PyQt5 Access MainWindow from Another Window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am newbie and in that project I am stuck at one point. How can I access functions in `MainWindow` class from another Window.

For example I need to access `Main.list_refresh` when `Child_EditAccount.btn_EDIT_ACCOUNT_3.clicked` . I tried something like signal & slot but doesn't work. I maked 3 different Window with pyQt Designer and I need to link the three together.

new.py

```
# Designs
from design import Ui_MainWindow
from design_addAccount import Ui_MainWindow_Add
from design_editAccount import Ui_MainWindow_Edit

# Modules
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('shorts.sqlite3')
cur = con.cursor()

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        

        self.account_process = AccountProcess()
        self.ui.lst_accounts.itemClicked.connect(self.account_process.edit_account)
        
        self.ui.btn_delete_account.clicked.connect(self.account_process.delete_account)
        self.ui.btn_edit_account.clicked.connect(self.account_process.edit_account)
        self.ui.btn_add_account.clicked.connect(self.account_process.add_account)
        self.ui.btn_refresh.clicked.connect(self.list_refresh)
        
        
        self.refresh_trigger = Child_EditAccount()
        self.refresh_trigger.buttonClicked.connect(self.list_refresh)
        
    def list_refresh(self):
        self.ui.lst_accounts.clear()
        for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users"):
            self.ui.lst_accounts.addItem('%s' % (str(row[3])))
    

class Child_AddAccount(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow_Add):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Child_AddAccount, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow_Add()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
class Child_EditAccount(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow_Edit):
    buttonClicked = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Child_EditAccount, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow_Edit()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    
    
    def edit_infos(self, username, password, nickname, id):
        self.id = id
        self.ui.txtBox_username_3.insert(username)
        self.ui.txtBox_password_3.insert(password)
        self.ui.txtBox_nickname_3.insert(nickname)
        self.ui.btn_EDIT_ACCOUNT_3.clicked.connect(self.update_by_id)

    
    def update_by_id(self):
        cur.execute('UPDATE users SET username="%s", password="%s", nickname="%s" WHERE id=%s' % (self.ui.txtBox_username_3.text(), self.ui.txtBox_password_3.text(), self.ui.txtBox_nickname_3.text(), self.id))
        con.commit()
                
        self.buttonClicked.emit()
    
        
      
class AccountProcess(QtCore.QObject):
    def add_account(self):
        self.child_add = Child_AddAccount()
        self.child_add.show()
        print('Pressed edit button')

    def delete_account(self):
        print('Pressed delete button')
    
    def edit_account(self, item):
        self.child_edit = Child_EditAccount()
        for i in cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname=\"{item.text()}\";"):
            self.child_edit.edit_infos(str(i[1]), str(i[2]), str(i[3]), str(i[0]))
        self.child_edit.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `pyqtSignal` to do what you want.
in the `Child_EditAccount` class add a `pyqtsignal`

```
class Child_EditAccount(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow_Add):
    buttonClicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
```

before the `__init__`, then when you need to trigger the function use

```
buttonClicked.emit()
```

in the function where the button is used in the `Child_EditAccount` class

Then in the main window, you can create a connection to a function via the `pyqtsignal`

```
self.Child_EditAccount.buttonClicked.connect(self.myfunction)
```

in the `__init__` of the main class. where `self.Child_EditAccount` is the instance of your `Child_EditAccount` class and `self.function` is the function you want to trigger `Main.list_refresh`

You can also create a signal from QtDesigner itself when you create the `Ui_MainWindow_Edit`
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-connection-mode.html

be carefull, `Child_EditAccount` inherite from `Ui_MainWindow_Add`  instead of `Ui_MainWindow_Edit` probably.

### ____

what you can also do is link the sigal of the button directly in the main program as in this little example

```
# Modules
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

class Main2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main2, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.but= QtWidgets.QPushButton('tdvfdbt')
        self.l = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.l.addWidget(self.but)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.l) 

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.win = Main2()
        self.a = self.win.show()

        self.win.but.clicked.connect(self.myfunction)

    def myfunction(self):
        print('called from sub window')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Model micro GUI')
    # ex.showMaximized()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

if you know the name of the button widget of the `Child_EditAccount` class you can link it via

```
  self.Child_EditAccount.btn_EDIT_ACCOUNT_3.clicked.connect(self.myfunction)
```

##______

Put the `pystsignal` in the `AccountProcess` class

```
class AccountProcess(QtCore.QObject):
    buttonClicked = pyqtSignal()
    def add_account(self):
        self.child_add = Child_AddAccount()
        self.child_add.show()
        print('Pressed edit button')

    def delete_account(self):
        print('Pressed delete button')

    def edit_account(self, item):
        self.child_edit = Child_EditAccount()
        for i in cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname=\"{item.text()}\";"):
            self.child_edit.edit_infos(str(i[1]), str(i[2]), str(i[3]), str(i[0]))
        self.child_edit.buttonClicked.connect(self.EmitAgain)
        self.child_edit.show()

    def EmitAgain(self):
        self.buttonClicked.emit()
```

Then use it in the main class

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.account_process = AccountProcess()
        self.account_process.buttonClicked.connect(self.list_refresh)
```

Comment: Thank you, almost done. Now there is no error but nothing happened. Edited Child_EditAccount class inherite from Ui_MainWindow_Add to Ui_MainWindow_Edit.  Added buttonClicked = pyqtSignal() to Child_EditAccount before  __init__ function. Added         self.buttonClicked.emit()   to update_by_id(self) function in Child_EditAccount class and added         self.refresh_trigger = Child_EditAccount()
        self.refresh_trigger.buttonClicked.connect(self.list_refresh)  to __init__ in Main class. What am I doing wrong? I edited the code with your suggestion.

Comment: can you print something before and after `self.buttonClicked.emit()`to see if you pass in that part of the code. and also in the `def list_refresh(self): function to see if you enter in it.`

Comment: When I click btn_EDIT_ACCOUNT_3 Before and after prints passes from self.buttonClicked.emit() but list_refresh function just prints at first run.

Comment: I see, it is not the correct intance. I updated the post. the signal must transit via the `AccountProcess` class

Comment: Thank you so much. You' re amazing. I've been struggling for 2 days just for this problem and you solved.  How did you understand this problem? What do i need to look again. Thank you again.